# "Aggregating" non-numeric variables in Reshape

Tags: r, aggregate, reshape

I have a dataset in long format and would like to convert it into a wide format using Reshape or any pre-processing prior to Reshape. The difficulty is that "value" variable is non-numeric. Note there is a legit duplicate record in the original data as well. The following code shows data layout for each.

```
id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
month <- c("jan", "feb", "feb", "march", "april", "april", "april")
stress <- c("mild", "mild", "high", "moderate", "mild", "high", "mild")
Longdata <- data.frame(id, month, stress, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

This is the orginal format:

```
> Longdata
  id month   stress
1  1   jan     mild
2  1   feb     mild
3  1   feb     high
4  1 march moderate
5  1 april     mild
6  1 april     high
7  1 april     mild
```

This is how I would like to get data organized:

```
id <- c(1)
jan <- c("mild")
feb <- c("mild-high")
march <- c("moderate")
april <- c("mild-high-mild")
widedata <- data.frame(id, jan, feb, march, april, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> widedata
  id  jan       feb    march          april
1  1 mild mild-high moderate mild-high-mild
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two steps, first using `aggregate`, and second using either base R `reshape` or `dcast` from the "reshape2" package.

1. The aggregation step:

   ```
   Mediumdata <- aggregate(stress ~ id + month, Longdata, paste, collapse="-")
   Mediumdata
   #   id month         stress
   # 1  1 april mild-high-mild
   # 2  1   feb      mild-high
   # 3  1   jan           mild
   # 4  1 march       moderate
   ```
2. The reshaping step:

   ```
   # Using base R reshape
   reshape(Mediumdata, direction="wide", idvar="id", timevar="month")
   #   id   stress.april stress.feb stress.jan stress.march
   # 1  1 mild-high-mild  mild-high       mild     moderate

   # Using `dcast` from "reshape2"
   dcast(mediumdata, id ~ month, value.var="stress")
   #   id          april       feb  jan    march
   # 1  1 mild-high-mild mild-high mild moderate
   ```